# EF Core не позволяет создать связь между таблицами многие ко многим, если Id одной из сущности равен 0

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, foreign-key

У меня есть три таблицы, представленные сущностями:

```
    public class Verification
    {
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationEntry
    {
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }
        public VerificationGroup VerificationGroup { get; set; }
        public Verification Verification { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationGroup
    {
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Идентификаторы могут иметь отрицательные значения и даже 0 (условия из ТЗ, ввод идентификаторов пользовательский).

При добавлении в БД средствами EF Core сущностей с идентификаторами не равными 0, всё спокойно добавляется. Если использовать 0 в качестве идентификатора, то возникает исключение.
Пример исключения при попытке создать VerificationEntry между уже существующими Verification и VerificationGroup с идентификатороми 0 и 3 соответственно:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
"The value of 'VerificationEntry.VerificationId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. 
This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which 
the principal entity in the relationship is not known.
```

Допустим при добавлении новой сущности с идентификатором 0 возникает и такая ошибка (логов приходит очень много, вот думаю информативная часть):

```
"Exception":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. 
See the inner exception for details.
\r\n ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 
23505: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности \"pk_verification_groups\"\r\n\r\n
DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. 
Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.\r\n
```

При этом, ручное добавление таких данных в БД работает нормально.
В чём может быть дело?

P.S. Сущностей с такими идентификаторами в БД не было для случая простого создания `Verification` или `VerificationGroup`

P.S.S При создании связи между сущностями `Verification` и `VerificationGroup` через `VerificationEntry` уже были соответствующие сущности с Id = 0, которые были созданы в БД вручную.

Comment: Не используйте введенные пользователем данные как первичный ключ. Используйте стандартный первичный ключ с автоинкрементом, а пользовательский - в отдельное поле таблицы. Еще код бы увидеть, вызывающий исключение.

Comment: @aepot да, я бы с радостью не использовал, но вот такие требования(((
Исключение вызывает стандартный метод EF Core SaveChangeAsync, перед этим просто добавление сущности с помощью AddAsync. Это всё отлично срабатывает для идентификаторов не равных нулю

Comment: Быть может вы требования не так поняли, они идут вразрез с хорошими практиками проектирования БД.

Comment: @aepot хотя бы это я смог точно понять :) в требованиях даже есть отрицательные идентификаторы о_о

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло добавление атрибутов к ID моделей, которые отключают режим создания ключей базой данных. То есть база данных получает тот ID, который был отправлен сервисом. По всей видимости БД идентификатор со значением 0 обрабатывала как NULL и пыталась создать для него свой ID.

Вот как теперь выглядят мои модели:

```
    public class Verification
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationEntry
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }

        public VerificationGroup VerificationGroup { get; set; }

        public Verification Verification { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class VerificationGroup
    {
    
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, там чётко написано:

23505: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности

То есть в таблице VerificationGroup уже есть запись с таким ключом.

Comment: В базе данных не было такой сущности в том то и дело. По всей видимости EF Core сущности с Id = 0 обрабатывал как NULL и просил БД генерировать айдишник самостоятельно. Так как там были идентификаторы и 1 и 2, то скорее всего база ругалась при попытке присвоить ему другое значение. Помогло присвоение идентификаторам сущностей атрибута [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]